# Accessing phpmyadmin database from terminal

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have a database in phpmyadmin. 
How can I access database of phpmyadmin from ubuntu terminal?

Answer (score 4):

You can connect to a mysql server using the `mysql` command

`mysql --user=USERNAME -p --host=HOSTNAME --database=DATABASENAME`

This will then prompt you for the password for the specified user (because the password switch was `-p` instead of `--password=PASSWORD`). Press return without typing anything for no password.

You can find more information on how to use the command by typing `man mysql` or `mysql --help` into your terminal.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot find my phpmuadmin database from the terminal using the 'show databases' command

Comment: @Parag are you using the same username and password in the terminal that you use for phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u <username> -p<password> <database_name>
```

Make sure no space between -p and password. Of course, this password will be visible in history.

To overcome this:

```
1.Leave it blank and it will ask you for it.
2.start the command with a space in front of mysql
```

Comment: I cannot find my phpmyadmin database from the mysql installed via terminal. Why? Any idea?